# How to use `$size` with embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having difficulty getting the size of arrays within embedded documents.

Given a collection with some document:

```json
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "60e26137600b71f2939ebbe7" },
    "name": "Outer doc",
    "inner_docs": [
        { "name": "one", "vals": [1,2,3,4,5] },
        { "name": "two", "vals": [1,2,3,4] },
        { "name": "three", "vals": [1,2,3] }
    ]
}
```

By applying a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage in [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) with [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) like:

```json
{
  "outer_num": { "$size": "$inner_docs" },
  "inner_docs.num_vals": { "$size": "$inner_docs.vals" }
}
```

I get the resultant doc:

```json
{
    "_id": { "$oid": "60e26137600b71f2939ebbe7" },
    "inner_docs": [
        { "name": "one", "num_vals": 3 },
        { "name": "two", "num_vals": 3 },
        { "name": "three", "num_vals": 3 }
    ],
    "outer_num": 3,
}
```

`outer_num` is correct, but `num_vals` is not, it should be the values `5`, `4` and `3` respectively.

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/dpsp907E_fa

Use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

> Applies an expression to each item in an array and returns an array with the applied results.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
        "outer_num": { $size: "$inner_docs"},
        "inner_docs": {
            $map: {
              input: "$inner_docs",
              as: "doc",
              in: { name: "$$doc.name", num_vals: { $size: [ "$$doc.vals" ] } }
            }
      }
    }
  }
])
```